# Intellij TypeScript Variable Name Autocomplete

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

In Java, you usually type the type when you declare a variable or field.

eg:

```
public SomeDataType someDataType = new SomeDataType(123)
```

when you start typing `Som..` the intellij autocomplete will probably start suggesting `SomeDataType` and you can hit tab to apply it.

When you've declared that the type is SomeDataType, when you start writing the name `som..` it will suggest `someDataType` for the variable name.

In Java there is an obvious flow. what you actually type is

```
pu[tab]Som[tab]som[tab]
```

in TypeScript, you do it the other way round

```
public someDataType: SomeDataType;
```

is there something similar for TypeScript in intellij? currently afaik, to get the same behavior you have write

```
pu[tab]:Som[tab][crtl + <-][ctrl + <-]som[tab][ctrl + ->][ctrl + ->]
```

which is extremely awkward and flowbreaking. it's even worse when your linter expects a lot of spaces.

what's the real trick here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **JavaScript/Suggest variable names** enabled in **Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion**, IDEA suggests names based on project types for new variables during their declaration:

[image]

Comment: pretty good! ticking "suggest variable names" and "suggest type annotations with parameter names" speeds things up a lot. thanks!